# Fedora Server 36 - update process automatically closes user’s session

Tags: fedora, users, login, repository, software-updates

This latest Saturday and today, through `VirtualBox` for `Fedora Server` **36**, as many times as I did do, was executed the `sudo dnf update` command, the password is written and

```
Starts to load and show some information. 
It about the progress bar loading and retrieving the metadata from the repositories
```

Normally after of the latest point mentioned above, the process itself asks for my confirmation to start the update process with `Y` … but instead …

#### Problem

- The user’s session is **closed** *automatically*.

If again I do the login and write the `sudo dnf update` command then the user’s session is **closed** *automatically*

Why happens this situation? how to fix it? In what log file would get more details about this?

Comment: Check journal (`journalctl -r`) for errors, I guess you don't have enough RAM and OOM killer killed your session. (DNF needs [at least 1 GB RAM for the update](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1907030).)

Comment: I couldn't find some clue through the `journalctl -r` command - it about the report. But you were right, it was about the RAM - about `VirtualBox` wondered why from 4GB it had 1GB instead - It was fixed and works. Please post your answer to mark it as valid. Huge thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your session was probably killed by OOM killer -- DNF needs relatively lot of RAM (there is [an open bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1907030) about `dnf update` failing on systems with <= 1 GiB of RAM). You can check the logs, look for lines looking like *Out of memory: Killed process ...* in the `journalctl -r` output. Because this is a VM simply adding some more RAM should be an easy fix.

Comment: Thanks - through the `journalctl -r | grep "killed"` command appears many times something like _systemd-oomd killed 4 process(es) in this unit_